# Is it possible to have more than one sticky column with Angular Flex?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have an angular material table with information columns and date columns. I want to have the information columns stay at the left side, mean sticky.

I have already tried to add the "sticky"-tag to all the columns I want sticky but didn´t work out.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" >
  <ng-container matColumnDef="group" sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell class="group" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Konzern </th>
    <td mat-cell class="group" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.group}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="customer"sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell class="customer" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Kunde </th>
    <td mat-cell class="customer" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customer}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="brand" sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell class="brand" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Marke </th>
    <td mat-cell class="brand" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.brand}} </td>
  </ng-container>


  <ng-container matColumnDef="subBrand" sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell class="subBrand" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Submarke </th>
    <td mat-cell class="subBrand" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.subBrand}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="subgroup" sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell class="subgroup" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Untergruppe </th>
    <td mat-cell class="subgroup" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.subgroup}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let week of this.displayedRowInformation; let i=index" [matColumnDef]="i.toString()">
    <th mat-header-cell class="week" [id]="i.toString()" *matHeaderCellDef> {{week.weeknumber}} </th>
    <td mat-cell class="week" *matCellDef="let element">
      <div style="position:relative">
        <div>{{ getEvent(week, element).description}}</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please set your code here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-table fork and show us link

Answer (score -3):

I think [this site](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs) could help you. You can check by changing the options in the site.

> https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs